# Creating a materialized view in Azure Cosmos for Cassandra from a base table with composite primary key

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

We are trying to migrate from Cassandra to Azure Cosmos for Cassandra. One of the challenges is in creating materialized views from existing materialized views. The existing base table has a composite primary key. If the base table has a composite primary key then we are not able create a materialized view with the existing composite key with another key. What are the alternatives that can be done other than altering the base table to remove the composite key

We tried to remove the composite key from the base table. It will have implications on the client side to handle duplicates. Is there an option to create a materialized view with the composite key retained in the base table in Azure cosmos db for cassandra

Message: {"Errors":["Materialized view creation is not supported on a source collection whose Partition Kind is MultiHash"]} –

This happens when the base collection has a composite partition key with 2 or 3 columns

Comment: Please edit to provide all relevant details.

Comment: Details should be in your question, not as a comment. Also, there's just no way to discuss future features or compatibility here. Aside from that: when you edit your question, please show specifics (actual data/schema, behavior issues, errors, etc)

Comment: Added the exact error message. Hope this clarifiles